# where do i put my main layout in the axml

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i copied over a example project so i can use and edit the side menu it has. but i'm not sure where i put my normal code now that is supposed to show me the main page(the stuff thats not on the menu).

this is my axml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the example does not explain on how i am supposed to continue using this.

regards,

Bjorn

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You have to put your main layout contents inside the Relative Layout under Toolbar inside Drawer Layout as I have placed WebView in my layout.      


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/leftNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/appDescriptionLayout"
                layout="@layout/app_description_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: one more question. in the include everything i put expands over the whole page. but i don't want it on top of my bar on the top of my page. i start it with a linear view. but not sure on what to put so they don't overlap.

Comment: In my answer i have added the toolbar by using include tag.

Comment: You have added toolbar directly in your Relative layout. So please put another contents below toolbar using "         android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar""

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer as accepted & upvote it so that others may refer this solution to the problem.